# How to get the first N words of an org file's main body

Tags: org-mode, string

Given an org-mode file like this

```
#+TITLE: My title
#+AUTHOR: Me Myself

First and so on words sixth this we don't want
```

How can I get the first *N* words of the main body?  So for *N=5*, I would like to get the string `First and so on words`.

If possible, links should only count with their `desc`.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't thoroughly tested, and I'm not really sure what parts of Org file to treat as its main body, but here you go:

```
(defun my/first-n-org-words (n)
  (interactive "nHow many words: ")
  (let ((buf (get-buffer-create "*org-first-words*"))
        results)
    (catch t
      (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
          '(headline iterm paragraph plain-list verse-block)
        (lambda (record)
          (cl-destructuring-bind (kind options &rest contents) record
            (let ((begin (plist-get options :begin))
                  (cnt (if (and contents (stringp (car contents)))
                           (car contents)
                         (or (car (plist-get options :title))
                             (plist-get options :value)))))
              (when cnt
                (setq results
                      (append results
                              (split-string 
                               (substring-no-properties cnt 0 (length cnt))
                               "[ \t\n]+" t)
                              results))
                (when (>= (length results) n)
                  (throw t nil))))))))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert (mapconcat 'identity results "\n")))
    (pop-to-buffer buf)))
```

If you are unhappy about what parts of the Org file it looks into, change the second argument of `org-element-map`.  To see what values are possible, look at the value of `org-element-all-elements`.